# How to open a Keyboard on focus on text input?

Tags: react-native, detox

In iOS simulator I can toggle software keyboard (`⌘K`) manually under Hardware main menu, and then tests pass. And I have to do it after Hardware Restart each time. But how can we make detox always open soft keyboard when an input field receives focus? Once soft keyboard is enabled it will stay enabled until next hardware restart, but tests will fail otherwise (soft keyboard won't show up on text input focus)

Answer (score 1):

We've recently changed the way we do typing in Detox. Starting with Detox 13, it is no longer necessary to disconnect the hardware keyboard and show the software keyboard. Please upgrade your Detox and you should see this new behavior immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try MAYUS+CMD+K instead of CMD+K

Comment: I would like framework to enable it or to have it enabled by default before running tests.